# Storing and loading in an SQL server 2008 database to an ASP.NET web page

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio-2010, sql-server-2008

I'm making a page for a simple shopping website using visual studio 2010 (ASP.NET). 
I have an SQL server database with sample products in it. Each product has an associated image I would like to load into a datagrid on a web page. So far I've tried storing the images as URLs and local directories (data type - text) but no joy. Any ideas?

Comment: Can you provide some more information? It is unclear to offer any advise.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for asking Manoj, I've actually managed to solve my issue using the following link if anyone should need it: msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

My image URL was set as "text" data type in the SQL server database I then followed the instructions in the link. I'm happy to provide further help on the subject to anyone who might need it.

Comment: Congrats on the fix.  When you are able, please mark your answer as 'accepted' to help others find your solution.  Cheers~